# ggplot2 : Plotting a covariance matrix as heat map without row/column names

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a covariance matrix, small selection here:

```
m <- matrix(c(2.61949322E+00, 2.27966995E+00, 1.68120147E+00,
              2.27966995E-01, 2.31885465E+01, 1.53558372E+00,
              1.68120147E+00, 1.53558372E+00, 1.26129096E+00),
            nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
```

So no header/row information is there. How can I plot a simple heatmap based on these values if there is no x/y information present?

A direct matrix doesn't work, so I already used `as.data.frame` to convert to a dataframe, but then i'm not sure.

I tried to melt with

```
require(reshape2)

m_melted <- melt(m)

ggplot(m_melted, aes(x= Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile()
```

But R hangs/crashes when doing this.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the `reshape` package and not `reshape2`? `reshape` gives other names than `Var1`/`Var2`.

Comment: typo, did that part quickly out of my head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing I changed was :

```
ggplot(m_melted, aes(x= Var1, y = Var2, fill = as.numeric(value))) +
  geom_tile()
```

And it works now. not sure why R was crashing prior, but probably was unrelated to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Is it because you're using `bm_test` as the data instead of `m_melted`?:

```
m <- matrix(c(2.61949322E+00, 2.27966995E+00, 1.68120147E+00,
              2.27966995E-01, 2.31885465E+01, 1.53558372E+00,
              1.68120147E+00, 1.53558372E+00, 1.26129096E+00),
            nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)

m_melted <- melt(m)

ggplot(m_melted, aes(x= X1, y = X2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile()
```